# ¿Por qué strlen me corrompe la cadena de texto?

Tags: c, string, gcc

Estaba jugando con C, e intentaba conseguir el tamaño de una cadena de texto char*, al poner la variable char* en la función strlen el programa por alguna razón no funcionaba y se cerraba sin dar ninguna pista de lo que sucedió.

```c
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
        char* texto;
        int len = 0;

        printf("Introduce un numero: ");
        scanf("%s", &texto);

        len = strlen(texto);
        
        // Aquí no muestra nada
        printf("La cadena es: %s\n", &texto);

        return 0;
}
```

Entonces lo cambie de está otra forma, y aunque me da una advertencia, me logra dar el tamaño de la cadena pero me corrompe el texto original

```c
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
        char* texto;
        int len = 0;

        printf("Introduce un numero: ");
        scanf("%s", &texto);

        len = strlen(&texto);

        // Funciona! A medias
        printf("La cadena es: %s\n", &texto);
        printf("El tamaño es: %d", len);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh. ¿Entonces como podría conseguir una cadena de texto con un tamaño definido por el usuario y su longitud?

Comment: Maldición, bueno... Igual gracias, creo que usaré un buffer de tamaño fijo. Aunque me gustaría que hubiera strings dinámicas en C, y pensaba que usando char* se solucionaba.
Usando char* si puedo hacer strings "dinámicas" sin definir un fin de buffer, ya que si pruebo eso sin buffer funciona, pero parece que no puedo conseguir su tamaño, aunque tengo una idea.

Comment: Tal como usas la variable `texto` en tu programa, deberías haberla declarado como `char **texto`, pues la usas como si fuera un puntero a puntero. Con la declaración `char *texto` no deberías poner esos `&` delante en ninguno de los usos posteriores. En cualquiera de los dos casos, el puntero **no está inicializado**, por lo que es normal que no funcione (con independencia de que no puedas especificarle un tamaño a scanf, que ese es otro problema)

Comment: @Mauricio Un buffer siempre tendrá un límite.. lo que puedes hacer es crear tu propia función `readLine` (tipo `c#`) en la cual se encargue de redimensionar el buffer cada vez que sea necesario. Aquí tienes un [ejemplo](https://gist.github.com/MrDave1999/09b90de748b9da01490a724aef3df98d).. Para lograr esto, debes usar la función `realloc`.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Genial, gracias. Estoy aprendiendo C, así que tengo estos pequeños problemas, mis principales problemas son con stdin mas que nada, lo demás en C es bastante simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La declaración de una variable con un `*` delante no la convierte automáticamente en "dinámica". Lo único que estás declarando es que la variable, en lugar de contener un dato, contiene la *dirección* de un dato.

Esa variable debe ser en cualquier caso inicializada para que *apunte* a una dirección de memoria donde haya espacio suficiente para el dato en cuestión.

Vamos con tu ejemplo:

```
char *texto;
```

Indica simplemente que `texto` es una variable cuyo contenido es **una dirección**. Esa dirección apuntará a una zona de la memoria donde habrá un `char` (pues ese es el tipo que has puesto a la izquierda del asterisco). Es decir, tienes un "puntero a char".

Los punteros a char suelen usarse como sinónimo de "cadena de caracteres", pero no son en absoluto lo mismo. Un puntero a char es simplemente una variable que contiene una dirección en la cual habrá un char. Una cadena en cambio es una secuencia de varios char, almacenados contiguos en memoria y terminados por un char con un valor especial que actúa de "terminador". Ese valor especial es el 0 (ascii 0, no carácter `'0'`).

La confusión entre puntero a char y cadena proviene de que todas las funciones de la biblioteca estándar C que manejan cadenas, esperan como parámetro un puntero a char. La razón es que ese puntero apuntará al *primer* char dentro de la cadena, y las funciones entienden que a continuación de ese habrá más char hasta llegar a uno con el valor 0.

Sabiendo esto, ¿qué hace la siguiente instrucción?

```
scanf("%s", texto)
```

La función `scanf()` al ver un `"%s"` en la cadena de formato, espera que el siguiente parámetro sea un puntero a char. Es decir, que sea una dirección de memoria. En esa dirección irá metiendo lo que el usuario escriba (en posiciones contiguas) y finalmente introducirá un byte 0 para indicar el final.

El problema en este caso es que la variable `texto` no está inicializada por lo que lo que contiene es un valor "aleatorio". Ya que ese valor se interpreta como una dirección de memoria, básicamente se tiene que el puntero `texto` apunta a una dirección aleatoria. En esa dirección será donde `scanf()` dejará el texto escrito por el usuario.

Naturalmente esta acción es potencialmente peligrosa, ya que no sabemos a dónde está apuntando realmente ese puntero. Es probable que, por puro azar, esté apuntando a posiciones de memoria protegidas por el operativo. En ese caso el intento de escribir en ellas causará una excepción en la CPU que terminará con un *segfault* y la terminación del programa.

Pero también por puro azar podría estar apuntando a una dirección de memoria no protegida (por ejemplo a otra variable de tu programa). En ese caso modificará esa variable con efectos imprevisibles.

### Tu intento de arreglarlo

Has puesto `&texto` en vez de `texto` en la llamada a `scanf()` ¿Qué cambia eso?

Cuando pones `texto` le estás pasando a `scanf()` el valor de ese puntero, que como vimos era un valor aleatorio con los peligros que eso conlleva.

Cuando pones `&texto` le estás pasando a `scanf()` **la dirección del propio puntero**. En ese caso no hay peligro de que esa dirección sea "aleatoria". El puntero está almacenado en tu programa, es parte de él, y por tanto la dirección en la que ese puntero está guardado no está protegida. Se puede meter información en ella.

El problema es que `scanf()` dejará la cadena escrita por el usuario en la dirección reservada para el puntero, en lugar de en la dirección apuntada por el puntero.

Un puntero, como cualquier otra variable, se guarda en memoria pero ocupa relativamente poco. Su tamaño depende de la arquitectura del sistema. Si es de 32 bits, el puntero ocupa 32 bits. Si es de 64 bits, el puntero ocupará 64. Consideremos el segundo caso. 64 bits son 8 bytes, asi que la memoria reservada para el puntero son 8 bytes.

Al pasarle `&texto` estás usando esa zona reservada de 8 bytes para guardar cadenas. Aparte de que conceptualmente está mal, se tiene el efecto sencundario de que no podrías guardar cadenas de más de 7 caracteres (pues el octavo se requiere para el terminador).

No solo eso, sino que después intentabas:

```
strlen(texto);
```

En ese momento la variable `texto`, en vez de contener una dirección de memoria donde estaría la cadena, contiene directamente la cadena (porque habías usado el `&texto` en `scanf()`. Pero `strlen()` va a interpretar el contenido de `texto` como una dirección de memoria donde ir a buscar la cadena cuya longitud debe medir. Los bytes almacenados en `texto` (que corresponderán a los códigos ascii de lo que el usuario haya escrito), serán interpretados como si fueran un número binario, la dirección de memoria donde estaría la cadena. Al intentar acceder a esa dirección de memoria lo más probable es que esté protegida y por tanto el programa rompa.

Esto lo "arreglaste" uando `strlen(&texto)`. Naturalmente no era esa la solución correcta pero funciona porque en este caso lo que recibe `strlen()` **sí es** una dirección de memoria donde hay una cadena. El problema vendría cuando esa cadena tenga más de 7 letras (en una arquitectura de 64 bits, en una de 32 bits el problema aparece aún antes, con cadenas de más de 3 letras).

## Solución

La solución es no usar `&texto`, sino `texto`. Y no tener `texto` sin inicializar, sino inicializarlo para que apunte a una zona de memoria de tamaño suficiente para albergar tu cadena. Naturalmente esto significa que necesitas conocer de antemano el tamaño de esa cadena.

Supongamos que sabes que el usuario nunca meterá más de 100 caracteres. En este caso puedes hacerlo así:

```
char *texto;

texto = malloc(101);   // 100 más uno para el terminador
scanf("%s", texto);
printf("%s", texto);
printf("%d", strlen(texto))
```

Todo funcionará correctamente siempre que el usuario no meta más de 100 caracteres. El problema es que *no hay forma de impedir que meta más*, y si lo hace el resto se saldrán de la zona reservada causando problemas (ya sea *segfault* o sobreescritura de otras variables).

Y por cierto que lo anterior se podría haber hecho también con un array de char, con idéntico resultado.

Por todo esto el uso de `scanf()` para leer cadenas se considera inseguro. Una posibilidad es usar `fgets()` que al menos admite un parámetro adicional para especificar el máximo número de caracteres a leer. Usando esto sería así:

```
fgets(texto, 100, stdin);
```

Al igual que `scanf()` irá tomando caracteres de la entrada estándar (pues hemos espeficado `stdin` en este caso, también vale para leer de ficheros), y los irá dejando en posiciones de memoria consecutivas, comenzando por la apuntada por `texto`. Pero a diferencia de `scanf()` sabe (porque le hemos pasado un 100 como segundo parámetro) que cuando haya escrito 100 caracteres debe detenerse y retornar (no sin antes escribir el 0 terminador, el cual es fundamental para que otras funciones de cadenas como `strlen()` puedan saber dónde termina).